# How to make use of the innvestigate package for LRP with tabular data?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, data-visualization

I am trying to get LIME and LRP working on a simple DNN with tabular data for some general usability evaluations of the two approaches with non-techsavy users. I managed to get LIME running to get an insight into the predictions of my network. Yet, I am having trouble implementing LRP with [innvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) to get insights into those predicitons.

So far I have created a relevance-based analyzer with:

```
import innvestigate

#create instance to analyze later on
data = (X_train,
        y_train,
        X_test,
        y_test)

instance_to_test = data[2][7:8] 

#create LRP analyzer
LRP_analyzer = innvestigate.analyzer.relevance_based.relevance_analyzer.LRPZ(model)

#analyze the specified instance
analysis = LRP_analyzer.analyze(instance_to_test)
```

Yet, after that I am stuck. What I want to do at the end, is taking my specified instance of the data and create a heatmap of the contributions to the classification result (meaning: relevance scores of the features for that instance). Has anybody worked with innvestigate (and this somewhat special use-case, as it is mainly used for image data) and can help me with that? I know that it should in theory be possible as I have seen LRP used with tabular data in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13429). Besides my code above I recieve the following error message when trying to get a heatmap displayed (see bottom of the post).

Yet, that should be because the general implementation requires an image tensor with 4 axes, which I can't provide. Any ideas for a workaround to make that happen for tabular data?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plt.imshow(analysis.squeeze(), cmap="seismic")
      2 plt.show()

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py:459, in make_keyword_only.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    453 if len(args) > name_idx:
    454     warn_deprecated(
    455         since, message="Passing the %(name)s %(obj_type)s "
    456         "positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib %(since)s; the "
    457         "parameter will become keyword-only %(removal)s.",
    458         name=name, obj_type=f"parameter of {func.__name__}()")
--> 459 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2650, in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, interpolation_stage, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2644 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.imshow)
   2645 def imshow(
   2646         X, cmap=None, norm=None, aspect=None, interpolation=None,
   2647         alpha=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, origin=None, extent=None, *,
   2648         interpolation_stage=None, filternorm=True, filterrad=4.0,
   2649         resample=None, url=None, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2650     __ret = gca().imshow(
   2651         X, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=aspect,
   2652         interpolation=interpolation, alpha=alpha, vmin=vmin,
   2653         vmax=vmax, origin=origin, extent=extent,
   2654         interpolation_stage=interpolation_stage,
   2655         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample,
   2656         url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
   2657         **kwargs)
   2658     sci(__ret)
   2659     return __ret

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py:459, in make_keyword_only.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    453 if len(args) > name_idx:
    454     warn_deprecated(
    455         since, message="Passing the %(name)s %(obj_type)s "
    456         "positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib %(since)s; the "
    457         "parameter will become keyword-only %(removal)s.",
    458         name=name, obj_type=f"parameter of {func.__name__}()")
--> 459 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1414, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1411 @functools.wraps(func)
   1412 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1413     if data is None:
-> 1414         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1416     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1417     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1418                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:5487, in Axes.imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, interpolation_stage, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5480 self.set_aspect(aspect)
   5481 im = mimage.AxesImage(self, cmap, norm, interpolation,
   5482                       origin, extent, filternorm=filternorm,
   5483                       filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample,
   5484                       interpolation_stage=interpolation_stage,
   5485                       **kwargs)
-> 5487 im.set_data(X)
   5488 im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5489 if im.get_clip_path() is None:
   5490     # image does not already have clipping set, clip to axes patch

File D:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\LRP_innvestigate\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:715, in _ImageBase.set_data(self, A)
    711     self._A = self._A[:, :, 0]
    713 if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    714         or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
--> 715     raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
    716                     .format(self._A.shape))
    718 if self._A.ndim == 3:
    719     # If the input data has values outside the valid range (after
    720     # normalisation), we issue a warning and then clip X to the bounds
    721     # - otherwise casting wraps extreme values, hiding outliers and
    722     # making reliable interpretation impossible.
    723     high = 255 if np.issubdtype(self._A.dtype, np.integer) else 1

TypeError: Invalid shape (10,) for image data
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Sadly I was not able to resolve the issue. Currently, I am in contact with the authors of the linked paper to better understand what problem is causing the roadblock. Will update you about the progress of that, if you want me to :)

Comment: Yes please, I have been trying to resolve this issue too. Please contact me at: hiratanveer0@gmail.com

Comment: I have had contact with the authors now. I will try to use their approach again, with some insights that I haven't had before. Will let you know if that worked for me. Nonetheless, that will take a few days. Will then reply back to you here on Stackoverflow, so that others might make use of that as well.

Comment: Looking forward